# How to get a list of unique properties from object

Tags: php

I have an array of objects with a 'category' property. I need to get a list of the different categories, how can I do this given that I have a method to get the category from the object? Shown below creates a list of all the categories in the array, but obviously has lots of repeated categories:

```
    foreach (getSourceCodes() as $source) {
        echo $source->getCategory();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `array_unique()` in php.

```
$categories = array();
foreach (getSourceCodes() as $source) {
    array_push($categories, $source->getCategory());
}
$categories = array_unique($categories);
```

If categories is multidimensional, then use this method to serialise it, then get unique array and then change it back to array.

```
$categories = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $categories)));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the category as an array key, it will be unique by definition.

```
foreach (getSourceCodes() as $source) {
    // The value is irrelevant. You can use a counter if you want to keep track of that.
    $an_array[$source->getCategory()] = true;
    // The key is just overwritten for duplicate values of getCategory()
}

// Then you can use array_keys to get the keys as values.
var_dump(array_keys($an_array));
```

Comment: Much appreciated, only preferred the other answer as there was more of an explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what format your list is in but assumed comma separated values...

```
$aCategories = array();
$aList = array();

    foreach (getSourceCodes() as $source) {
          // Get categories as comma separated string list???
           $sList = $source->getCategory();

           // Convert string list to array
           $aTmpList = explode(",",$sList);

           //Check temp list against current list for new categories
           $aDiffList = array_diff($aList,$atmpList);

           //Merge new categories into current list
            $aList = array_merge($aDiffList,$aList);
       }
       // Convert array to string list
       $sCategories = implode(",", $aList);
```